# Can I made an arbitrary discrete distribution be a parameter in other function,which generate another distribution?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

At first,I made a function with an integer parameter which generate a discrete distribution.

```
Alpha[x_Integer] := 
 ProbabilityDistribution[1/(Floor[x*2] - Floor[x] + 1), {x, Floor[x], Floor[x*2], 1}]
```

The function above generate a distribution which has the same probability among x to 2x, and it worked correctly.But then I realized that I should imply x as an distribution,so that Alpha can convert one distribution to another.

Specifically said,define Beta as another distribution below.

```
Beta = ProbabilityDistribution[1/2, {x, 1, 2, 1}]
```

Then I tried to feed it to Alpha by define Gamma.

```
Gamma[x_]:=TransformedDistribution[y,{y \[Distributed] Alpha[x],x \[Distributed] Beta}]
```

But it cannot work at all.
Can a distribution be implied in a function as well?If yes,how?